# Adding links to internet using an imagebutton in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am attempting to link to websites inside my app. I am using fragments, so I need to use binding. I have the ImageButtons set up already. I need the Java code that links to the website. I dont quite understand where everything goes

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {
 private FragmentDashboardBinding binding;
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);
    binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    return binding.getRoot();

    //*This section below gives me errors*

    public void openWebPage(String url){
       Uri facebook = Uri.parse(url);
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
       if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) !=null) {
          startActivity(intent);
       }
    }
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
 }
}
```

I need to open multiple different websites, using different buttons for each.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code. If you just want to open a web URL with an imagebutton.

Try this

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
binding =  FragmentMyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            openWeb("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        });
return binding.getRoot();
    }

// Class to handle Urls
public void openWeb(String url){
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No app found for handle this Url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Let me know if the problem not solved yet.